# Homework Problem Sheet Template

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, templates, tikz-styles, exercises

Could someone make this picture of Homework Problem Sheet Template in sample code in LaTeX with the same font size

by the way i already add tow pictures in the front of document to make it more cute
and if someone could inspire from that to make different template styles

for example to add colors to Box to make it more beautiful

[image]
any help would be appreciated

i tired

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}                                        
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
\draw (6,32) node {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{1.jpg}};
\draw (2.5,27) node {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{2.jpg}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\shadowsize-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
   \textcolor{black}{\sffamily INTEGRATION}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \textcolor{black}{\sffamily Professor : M.R. Educ}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \hspace*{\fill}


\end{minipage}}


\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 1: ]  Déterminer la sommabilité sur $I$ des fonctions suivantes:
\end{description}
Bla Bla Bla 

\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 2: ] 
Bla Bla Bla
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 3: ] 
Bla Bla Bla
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure of understanding your question. Are you after something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/boTXj.png ?

Comment: Is the problem the shadow is not in the desired place?

Comment: @HarishKumar Please see my update

Comment: @cfr as i want to make it identical twins so the shadow should be in the desired place. Thanks

Comment: You just edited the question. What do you mean by * inspire from that to make different template styles *? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Johannes_B for example to add colors to Box. Thanks for ur attention

Comment: Please add this information to the question above. This makes it easier to detect for other helpers. They don't need to read the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) it's easy to define your own shadows.

[image]

You'll have to adjust box dimensions, but next code could serve as starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}                                        
\begin{document}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%\begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
%\draw (6,32) node {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a.jpg}};
%\draw (2.5,27) node {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b.jpg}};
%\end{scope}
%\end{tikzpicture}

%\noindent
%\shadowbox{%
%\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\shadowsize-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
%   \textcolor{black}{\sffamily INTEGRATION}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
%  \textcolor{black}{\sffamily Professor : M.R. Educ}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
%    \hspace*{\fill}
%
%
%\end{minipage}}


\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=white, colframe=black, 
                  fontupper=\sffamily, sharp corners,
                  shadow={4pt}{4pt}{0mm}{black},boxrule=1pt]
 INTEGRATION \hfill SMA \hfill Semester 4\\
 Professor : M.R. Educ \hfill Year: 2013--2014\\
 \centerline{\rmfamily SÉRIE D'EXERCICES}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 1: ]  Déterminer la sommabilité sur $I$ des fonctions suivantes:
\end{description}
Bla Bla Bla 

\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 2: ] 
Bla Bla Bla
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[Exercice 3: ] 
Bla Bla Bla
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you inspire from that to make different template styles of HPST

Comment: @Educ I've my own one not very inspired, but you can find some more looking around: in [writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/gallery/tagged/homework#.VHWUc4uG-zw), [LateXtemplates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/assignments), [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+assignements), sharelatex, ...